# Trashing the content of managed variables

Tags: c#

I have an application using cryptography, mostly in streams (file and memory) which I decrypt as needed into a new MemoryStream. All this works well.
Only thing is, I would like to trash the content of the MemoryStream when I am done with it (as well as strings etc I copy portions into) to prevent it ever getting paged to disk in decrypted form via the swap file.
In "good old fashioned" C++ I would just blitz the data with random rubbish before I deleted it - is there any way with managed objects?

Comment: For string you should use `SecureString`.

Comment: What prevents it from being paged to disk in decrypted form *before* you are done with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the underlying byte[] using [MemoryStream.GetBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx), and then fill it with random data.

In an insecure context you would usually do this with [Random.NextBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), but in your case, [RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) provides a cryptographically secure random number generator as the source of the fill bytes.

After trashing the buffer, dispose of your MemoryStream normally by calling [MemoryStream.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You don't need a cryptographically secure PRNG for this purpose.  It would just be unnecessarily slow, increasing the time that the sensitive data spends in memory.

Comment: It is unlikely to work the way OP wants as GC can move (small) allocation around - so there is a chance that underlying byte array is copied by GC to some other place and not yet wiped out...